# Best way to handle a question I asked

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, specific-question

We were having a problem with an implementation in Java that mixed inheritance and an interface. When the code was not operating as expected, I though my understanding of how Java handled that was incorrect, so I asked the following question: *[Can a derived class override an interface method implemented in the base class in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46924963/can-a-derived-class-override-an-interface-method-implemented-in-the-base-class-i)*

It turns out that the problem was something unrelated and the implementation does work.

Now the questions is: What do I do with the question?

Should I:

1. Just delete it. I don't like this, because it seems still to be a well written valid question and so may be the answer to what another person asks.
2. Answer it myself and say it does work; but, the issues was something else.
3. Just leave it as it is (unanswered with clarification in the comments).

Comment: Either: Close as no reproducible. Modify the question so is reflects the _real_ problem and answer it then (unless there already exists such a q&a; or someone already answered yours). Delete it.

Comment: The real cause would have no relevance to anyone else.

Comment: If it’s not going to be helpful for future readers, just delete it.

Comment: It seems like it would be helpful.  The answer to the question is "yes" and if I would have know that, I might have found the real bug earlier rather than chasing this 'rabbit'.

Comment: If it would be useful, then you can edit it to be answerable. The answer needs to be useful, not the question. An unanswered question is _not_ useful.

Comment: If the "unrelated" problem is something that other programmers might run into, and you can provide a useful solution, then the question might be worth keeping around. Otherwise, close as not-reproducible and/or delete. (No issues with deleting, since it hasn't received any answers.)

Comment: Just because a question you have asked turns out not to be the question you should have asked doesn't mean that the asked question is poor or invalid. A question should be judged on the merits of the question itself and not whether the question is something you need an answer too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It turns out that the problem was something unrelated and the
>   implementation does work.

That is a textbook case for the close vote reason "Off topic -> Can't reproduce". For you this probably means you should delete it. I don't think this is a valid question because the answer (as you yourself admitted) will boil down to "No, your code works as expected, your problem is elsewhere".

Questions persist for future users. You yourself admitted that the real cause is very specific to your setup and thus not applicable to other users and of no concern to them. Thus, the same goes for your question, which is unlikely to help anyone else.

Comment: I deleted the post.